# how to get the total array of object

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, object, if-statement

So what I am trying to do for this project is create a function which is "findMyCampsites" That takes in three arguments which are campgrounds, views, and partySize. I am trying to get my code to take in an persons view preference "forest" or "ocean" and well as the size of there expected party and return the number of all available campgrounds matching the user input. But if there are no matches the function should return an empty array. Here is what i was able to come up with so far.. I can't figure out why i am returning [] no matter what. What am i doing wrong?

```
> function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize){
  let result = []
 for (i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++){
   if (campgrounds[i].isReserved === false){
      if (campgrounds[i].view === view){
         result.push(campgrounds[i].view)
       if (campgrounds[i].partySize === partySize){
       result.push(campgrounds[i].partySize)
     result = result + 1;
   

     }  
   } 
 }return result;

 }

}
```

also here is my campground object

```
> let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
]
```

Comment: Perfect use case for [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: do you want to return a number or the items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try formatting your code

```js
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize) {
  let result = [];
  for (i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    if (campgrounds[i].isReserved === false) {
      if (campgrounds[i].view === view) {
        result.push(campgrounds[i].view);
        if (campgrounds[i].partySize === partySize) {
          result.push(campgrounds[i].partySize);
          result = result + 1;
        }
      }
    } 
    return result; // inside the for loop
  }
}
```

You put the return statement inside your for loop.

The loop only run once before your function return.

Because the first element in `campgrounds` array has the key `isReserved` set to `false` (to say it programmatically, `campgrounds[0].isReserved === false`), nothing was pushed into the array before the function returns.

Comment: would this me the correct way to count the number of available 'views'?

Comment: @Maraysha Washington No. If you want to count the number of available views, you should check the length of the resulted array. e.g. `findMyCampsites( ... ).length`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.filter()`

You can chain your multiple conditions with an logical OR operator `&&`

First you check if its not reserved with `!ground.isReserved`. If this condition is met it moves to the next condition, otherwise it returns `false` and this current campground gets filtered out.

You can add more conditions, you just need to chain it with `&&`.

For the `partySize` i used greater equal `>=` rather then `===` because:

If somebody needs for example an size for 4 but there is for example an size for 5 the 5 ones would not be displayed to them. They would maybe still use the 5 even if its 1 size to much. Sure, if you want it strictly `===` then just replace `>=` with `===`

```js
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
]

function getCamp(campgrounds, view, size) {
   return campgrounds.filter(ground => !ground.isReserved && view === ground.view && ground.partySize >= size)
}

console.log(getCamp(campgrounds, "ocean", 4));
```

Comment: `isReserved` is the primary logic gate so I'd move that to the first check

Comment: Doesn't make much difference here but if the other checks were more complex, it's more efficient 

Comment: op did use a strict equality for party size, I'd add a comment to tell him about the change

Comment: @jonatjano yea you right. i was just thinking if there is an partysize of 5 but they only need like 4 so the campground would not be displayed to them. But maybe they would still use the campground even if they have 1 size more then they need

Comment: I'd have made the same change as you did, but op may not want it, that's why a comment to tell him feels like a good idea

Comment: I see It's doing the same thing as the last code i wrote. I am trying return the number of available campgrounds when a user ask for ocean view it should return 3 as well as partySize should return 1 for 8 or more people

Comment: @MarayshaWashington what is the desired output for this input i have here?

Answer (score 1):

You already have an answer about how to make it work, so I'll make one telling you why it doesn't work.

The problem comes from your return statement, you made it inside of the for loop while you should have made it after it. As you code is, it can return a value only if the matching campground is the first one.

That's why taking care of the indentation is important. below is your exact code, with better indentation.

```js
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize){
    let result = []
    for (i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
        if (campgrounds[i].isReserved === false) {
            if (campgrounds[i].view === view) {
                result.push(campgrounds[i].view)
                if (campgrounds[i].partySize === partySize){
                    result.push(campgrounds[i].partySize)
                    result = result + 1;
                }  
            } 
        }
        return result;
    }
}

let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
]

console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, "ocean", 8))
console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, "forest", 4))
```

---

same code with little corrections to make it works

```js
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize){
    let result = []
    for (i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
        if (campgrounds[i].isReserved === false) {
            if (campgrounds[i].view === view) {
                if (campgrounds[i].partySize === partySize){
                    // only push if all tests passed
                    result.push(campgrounds[i].view, campgrounds[i].partySize)
                    // removed the result = result + 1
                    // since it would transform result into a number
                    // and break the loop
                }  
            } 
        }
    }
    // return is as it's expected position
    return result;
}

let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
]

console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, "ocean", 8))
console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, "forest", 4))
```

Comment: Thank you but this code which is my code is still giving me empty arrays[ ]

Comment: yeah, it's giving empty array when the first camp is invalid, since the loop stop after the first camp everytime, that's the whole point of my example, showing you it works only if the first camp is valid, my answer is not here to give you the working code, but to make you understand where you made a mistake

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use a `for` loop, take [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and get the object directly without using an index (where you missed a declaration, which makes `i` global).

Inside of the loop you could reverse the checks and [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) early.

At the end of the loop, you got the wanted object.

```js
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, view, partySize) {
    let result = [];
    for (let ground of campgrounds) {
        if (ground.isReserved) continue;
        if (ground.view !== view) continue;
        if (ground.partySize !== partySize) continue;
        result.push(ground.number);
    }
    return result;
}

let campgrounds = [{ number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false }, { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false }, { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }, { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false }, { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }];

console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, 'ocean', 4));
```

Comment: i still get the empty array result for all input. if i input i want an ocean view and i have a party of for I am just trying to get the code to return the number that's available example [3,4]

Comment: sorry, i don't get you.

Comment: thanks my brother. I changed gound.partySize !== partySize to gound.partySize < partySize and the code worked perfectly